# How to turn Opportunity to Sales agreement in Manufacturing Cloud

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-marketing-cloud

is there a process in Manufacturing Cloud in which I can turn an opportunity to a Sales Agreement or do I need to make a Apex code to process it? and I would like to know where is the best to study the manufacturing cloud. because I am new to this. thank you.